# seagate faulty replacement hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, bad-blocks, seagate

My Seagate hard disk got bad sectors and wasn't usable any more. Seagate's SeaTools utility also indicates that. It was under warranty; so I returned that in Seagate SeaCare center and got a replacement drive within a few weeks. But even the replacement drive had the same problem of bad sectors and didn't even allow me to complete a Windows installation. So I visited the seagate service center one more time and got another replacement drive in a week's time. But to my surprise, that was faulty too and crashed during Windows installation. The SeaTools tests did confirm that both the replacement drives were indeed faulty.

Considering this I have following question for the community (and I hope I have chosen a right site out of stackexchange collection of sites):

1. I have read that these replacement drives are not brand new but only refurbished ones. (People at seacare center don't seem to have technical knowledge about it!) I wanted to know if that is really the case? And how can two replacement drives fail in a row?
2. More important question - do you think there might be anything wrong with my computer that's causing the disks to go bad so quickly? Whatever I know about computer hardware, this might not be the case. But I want to get opinions from experts out here before I decide to give up on my current disk and purchase a new one.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, yes, drives that you get back from such a "repair" both are not the exact drive you sent in, but also are not brand new.  They are almost always "remanufactured" or "recertified".  I once (years ago) called in on a drive I had just bought, and the vendor I purchased it from refused to do a replacement.  So I called the manufacturer, and she urged me not to do a replacement through them, because it wouldn't be a new drive.  She called my vendor and got them to do a replacement for me.

On your other question, could it be your computer?  That's kind of what I was thinking...  Have you tried these drives in another computer?  Could it be that you have a cabling issue, a problem with that port on your controller/motherboard/backplane?  Could it be that the drive isn't being cooled well enough (I've seen drives that were over their thermal limits report read/write issues).

I've never gotten a drive back from warranty repair that failed again right away.  We mostly use Hitachi drives, but have done some RMAs on Seagates as well and not had any problems.